# Binding dynamically generated form inputs to viewModel

Tags: .net, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

so I have been developing a web application with .NET 6. I have a form, which has a button that allows generating as many input rows as user wants. I tried to bind it with view model.

```
@model IEnumerable<AddToMealViewModel>

<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="addMore()">Add more</button>
<form method="post">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedMealId,
                         new SelectList(Model.Meals, "Id", "Name"),
                         "Select")
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedProductId,
                         new SelectList(Model.Products, "Id", "Name"),
                         "Select")
                <input asp-for="@Model.Amount" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</form>
<script>
    function addMore() {
        $(".row-fluid:last").clone().appendTo(".wrapper");
    }
</script>
```

The thing is, I have no idea how to automatically bind the newly generated fields to the ViewModel to pass to my Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dynamically generate input rows and bind them to your view model, you can try these steps:

**In Razor view**

```
@model IEnumerable<AddToMealViewModel>

<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="addMore()">Add more</button>
<form method="post">
    <div class="wrapper">
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.ElementAt(i).SelectedMealId, new SelectList(Model.ElementAt(i).Meals, "Value", "Text"), "Select")
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.ElementAt(i).SelectedProductId, new SelectList(Model.ElementAt(i).Products, "Value", "Text"), "Select")
                    <input asp-for="Model.ElementAt(i).Amount" />
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</form>
<script>
    var index = @Model.Count();
    function addMore() {
        var newRow = $(".row-fluid:last").clone();
        newRow.find(':input').val(''); // Clear input values
        newRow.find('select').prop('selectedIndex', 0); // Reset dropdowns
        newRow.find(':input').each(function () {
            var name = $(this).attr('name').replace(`[${index - 1}]`, `[${index}]`);
            $(this).attr('name', name);
        });
        newRow.appendTo(".wrapper");
        index++;
    }
</script>
```

**In controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult YourAction(IFormCollection form)
{
    // var dynamicColumn1= form["dynamicColumn1"];
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the complete result and quick answer! However, even though the compiler lets me through, and the form builds correctly, the model sent to the controller is empty. Has zero records, even though I've entered the data. Any ideas why would that be?

Comment: @klaudiaRajs you can work around this by using IFormCollection instead of a model to map dynamic columns.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to make that work!

Answer (score 0):

As I had a problem actually binding the result to the model, I'm posting the final solution below. If anyone finds any improvement, please do share it.

```
        public IActionResult AddToMeal(IFormCollection form)
        {
            List<AddToMealViewModel> ingredients = MapAddViewModelFromFormCollection(form); 
            return RedirectToAction("Today"); 
        }

        private List<AddToMealViewModel> MapAddViewModelFromFormCollection(IFormCollection form)
        {
            List<AddToMealViewModel> ingredients = new List<AddToMealViewModel>();
            int numberOfLines = form.First().Value.Count - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfLines; i++)
            {
                ingredients.Add(new AddToMealViewModel());
            }

            foreach (var item in form)
            {
                if (nameof(AddToMealViewModel.SelectedMealId) == item.Key)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < item.Value.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string? value = item.Value[i];
                        var viewModel = ingredients.ElementAt(i);
                        viewModel.SelectedMealId = int.Parse(value);
                    }
                }
                if (nameof(AddToMealViewModel.Amount) == item.Key)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < item.Value.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string? value = item.Value[i];
                        var viewModel = ingredients.ElementAt(i);
                        viewModel.Amount = int.Parse(value);
                    }
                }
                if (nameof(AddToMealViewModel.SelectedProductId) == item.Key)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < item.Value.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string? value = item.Value[i];
                        var viewModel = ingredients.ElementAt(i);
                        viewModel.SelectedProductId = int.Parse(value);
                    }
                }
            }
            return ingredients; 
        }
```